# How to use Classes As List Collection in Azure AppFabric Caching

Tags: azure

H, 
I am using the Windows Azure AppFabri Caching.
I have two project in asp.ne t .
One to put data in cache and 2nd to read that cache. These Two project are running on 2 different systems.
I have 4 dll included in these projects.

```
Microsoft.WindowsFabric.Common.dll
Microsoft.WindowsFabric.Data.Common.dll
Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client.dll
Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core.dll
```

Poject 1: To insert data in cache is using the following code:Data is saving to cache successfully

Default.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Salary { get; set; }

    }
    protected static DataCacheFactory _factory = null;
    protected static DataCache _cache = null;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PutDataIntoCache();

    }
    protected void PutDataIntoCache()
    {
        List<Employee> emp = new List<Employee>();
        try
        {

            emp.Add(new Employee { Name = "James", Salary = 20000 });
            PutCacheItem("55", emp);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
    protected void PutCacheItem(string key, object value)
    {

        try
        {
            _cache = GetDefaultCache();
            _cache.Put(key, value);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }
    }
    protected static DataCache GetDefaultCache()
    {
        _factory = new DataCacheFactory();
        _cache = _factory.GetDefaultCache();
        return _cache;

    }

}
```

Now I am reading the cache in another project that is running on another system.
Code is given below:

default.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected static DataCacheFactory _factory = null;
    protected static DataCache _cache = null;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetDataFromCache();

    }
    protected void GetDataFromCache()
    {
        _cache = GetDefaultCache();
        string key = "55";
        var item = _cache.Get(key);// Error is generation here
    }

    protected static DataCache GetDefaultCache()
    {
        _factory = new DataCacheFactory();
        _cache = _factory.GetDefaultCache();
        return _cache;

    }

}
```

An error is generating on the line _cache.Get(key)

```
The deserializer cannot load the type to deserialize because type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[_Default2+Employee, App_Web_4xzswv4j, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' could not be found in assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Check that the type being serialized has the same contract as the type being deserialized and the same assembly is used.
```

Why this error is coming?
How can Can I uses Classes as List collection to add/read in Cache.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that your second project doesn't define the Employee class. You should really define a class library with Employee in it and reference that same assembly from both projects.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've set these projects up, then I think ASP is compiling these code-behind pages into temporary assemblies - i.e. the Employee class is defined as being in the assembly `App_Web_4xzswv4j, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`

Instead, you should put these classes into a class library which can be shared between the projects - this will then have a fixed name, rather than a unique name for each compilation.

---

As an aside, I think you should also mark your Employee as serializable in order to ensure that it can be serialized and deserialized.