# "System.Collections.Generic.List`1" SerializationBinder BindToType

Tags: c#, serializationbinder

I have a web service which searializes and returns the following to a client as an array of bytes:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyFile
{
  public byte[] Data;
  public string FileName;
}
```

That is, I return a **List(Of MyFile)** to the client.

It is consumed by the client with the following TYPENAME

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[NorwayTaxService.Streaming+MyFile, NorwayTaxService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
```

with an assembly name of:

```
mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

I'm using the following two classes to bind to deserialize:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyFileLocal : ISerializable
{
  public byte[] Data;
  public string FileName;

  // The security attribute demands that code that calls 
  // this method have permission to perform serialization.
  [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, SerializationFormatter = true)]
  void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
  {
    info.AddValue("Data", Data);
    info.AddValue("FileName", FileName);
  }

  // The security attribute demands that code that calls   
  // this method have permission to perform serialization.
  [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, SerializationFormatter = true)]
  private MyFileLocal(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
  {
    Data = (byte[])info.GetValue("Data", Data.GetType());
    FileName = info.GetString("FileName");
  }
}

sealed class MyFileWebToLocalVersionBinder : SerializationBinder
{
  public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
  {
    Type typeToDeserialize = null;

    // For each assemblyName/typeName that you want to deserialize to 
    // a different type, set typeToDeserialize to the desired type.
    String assemVer1 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
    String typeVer1 = "NorwayTax.Streaming+MyFile";

    if (assemblyName == assemVer1 && typeName == typeVer1)
    {
      // To use a type from a different assembly version,  
      // change the version number. 
      // To do this, uncomment the following line of code. 
      // assemblyName = assemblyName.Replace("1.0.0.0", "2.0.0.0");

      // To use a different type from the same assembly,  
      // change the type name.
      typeName = "MyFileLocal";
    }


    typeToDeserialize = Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}, {1}", typeName, assemblyName));

    return typeToDeserialize;
  }
}
```

But for the life of me, and trying many, many variations on the GETTYPE statement, my TYPE is always NULL.

For example, per a post on STACKOVERFLOW, I tried:

```
typeToDeserialize = Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}, {1}", "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[NorwayTax.Streaming+MyFile, NorwayTax]]", assemblyName));
```

But it did not work :(

Comment: The ]] brackets are misplaced.

Comment: Assuming you mean 
typeToDeserialize = Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}, {1}]]", "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[NorwayTax.NorwayTaxService.StreamingService.Streaming+MyFile, NorwayTax", assemblyName)); ?

I have tried that and it throws an error.. please elaborate.

Comment: I think the key to unlock this is to instead focus on System.Collections.Generic.List since really, this type doesn't exist within my client assemly: NorwayTaxService.Streaming+MyFile.

Comment: My answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53537331/809974) question will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The object type I tried to deserialize didn't exist within client application / assembly.
I thought that by using the `SerializationBinder` I'd be able to cast it into an a similar object.

Here's the object, which is a serialized list / collection :

```
using System;

namespace NorwayTax
{
  public class NorwayTaxFiles
  {
    [Serializable]
    public class NorwayFile
    {
      public string FileName { set; get; }
      public byte[] Data { set; get; }
    }
  }
}
```

and perhaps it is possible to cast it into a similar collection but, for the life of me, I was unable to make it happen.

What I finally did was to isolate the above into its own DLL, which both my Web Service and client referenced and it worked flawlessly and without the need of the `SerializationBinder`.

Finally, whole point of this exercise was to pass from the web service multiple files in one pass utilizing Framework tools.  Interesting, the files I passed along are already compressed using **7z**, but broken apart, per the business requirment, into an archive set (.001, .002, etc.).

The inspiration for my solution came from this answer: [You should really define a class library with in it and reference that same assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6776538/890266).